# jqplot: Any way for different colors in a nested donut graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I use the donut renderer of jqplot to display muliple dontus.

Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Azd325/ef88x/

```
    seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        sliceMargin: 0,
        padding: 10,
        ringMargin: 10,
        seriesColors: ["#98C73D", "#00A9E0", "#67CDDC"],
        lineWidth: 5,
        startAngle: -90,
        innerDiameter: 10,
        shadow: false
    }
},
```

I tried around if may takes a nested list of colors lists but that was not working and I checked also that canvas markup to change the color.

Is there a way to get different colors for the nested donuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it is to create a series array. For each entry you can link a seriesColors array in order to specify particular colors for each series.

I have updated your [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/ef88x/3/) :

```
series: [
  {seriesColors: ["#98C73D", "#00A9E0", "#67CDDC", "#000"]}, 
  {seriesColors: ["#a30", "#4b0", "#b40", '#af0']},
  {seriesColors: ["#175", "#473", "#475", '#412']},
],
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was searching